# Вопрос по отношениям Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня есть таблицы users,branches,bases,user_branches

User список пользователей имеют связи с Branch  (один пользователь может быть привязан к многим филиалам)

```
 public function branches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Branch', 'user_branches');
    }
```

Base список клиентов тоже имеют связи с Branch (один клиент может быть привязан к одному филиалу)

```
public function base_branch(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'id', 'branch');
}
```

Как можно получить коллекцию клиентов к которым имеет отношение пользователь ?

К примеру пользователь привязан к филиалу с id 1 и 2 , соответственно получить коллекцию всех клиентов которые привязаны к этим филиалам

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку...

Comment: Нарисуйте схему связей - прямоугольники (обозначают таблицы, внутри написано название таблицы) и стрелочки (стрелочки обозначают связи). Словом схему БД. И конкретно напишите, какие данные вы имеете и что хотите получить, имея эти данные. Я может устал сильно, но ваше описание всего этого не осилил

Comment: Добавил схему БД

Comment: так и запись из какой таблицы у вас есть (на английском), и данные из каких таблиц вы хотите получить?

Comment: Схему заменил,получить коллекцию клиентов (base) к которым имеет отношение пользователь ?

К примеру пользователь(user) привязан к филиалу (branch) с id 1 и 2 , получить коллекцию всех клиентов (base) которые привязаны к этим филиалам

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял то:

//у 1 филиала должна быть связь к клиентам например

public function bases()

{

return $this->hasMany('App\Base', 'branch');

}

```
    //если у тебя уже получен клиент то раскладываем филиалы
    foreach ($user->branches as $branch) {
        //далее раскладываем филиал на список клиентов для получения списка имен например или сразу делаем каунт если просто нужно узнать количество клиентов смотря какая задача поставлена
        foreach ($branch->bases as $base) {
            # code...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможно ли на стороне контроллера сформировать готовую коллекцию и отправить? к примеру передать во vue

Comment: Да можно, для этого я использую Json:API и Axios

Comment: Я как раз тоже использую Json:API и Axios и Vue

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

1. Нужно сделать связь между филиалом и клиентом.
2. А после можете получить клиентов с помощью
   `User::with(['branches.bases'])->get();`

Comment: 2 пункт же раскладывать все равно путем перебора массивов через форич что бы получить клиентов всех?

Comment: @imvasha, не нужно. Laravel сделает все сам, в итоге мы получим в `$user->branches` коллекцию, каждый элемент которой будет уже содержать нужные данные `bases`.